# The equivalence principle and the existence first quantization?

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle, quantization

So imagine we are doing Einstein's famous thought experiment where we are locked in an elevator so narrow we are unable to detect tidal forces. The equivalence principle suggests that we should be unable to distinguish if we are accelerating due to gravity or a potential.

Let us assume it is a potential then I would expect the notion of first quantization to make sense for say system $X$. But we could also be instead near the surface of a black hole and travelling with non-relativistic velocities.

Does the equivalence principle suggest the notion of first quantization should make sense here for $X$? Because if it didn't I have a method of violating the equivalence principle since I can locally distinguish if gravity is causing the acceleration or not?

I've never seen this argument in the literature but it seems correct to me. Can someone shed some light on its validity?

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. Quantization is a *formal* procedure that from a formal description of a classical system constructs formal description of quantum system. Hypothetical failure of quantization is akin to compiler error on some source code: it may indicate an error of an algorithm (of quantization) or an error in the description of a system being quantized. By itself such failure does not give rise to an experiment that could be performed on a (real quantum) system.

Comment: @A.V.S. I was referring to systems where a $1$st quantization description may not be available and one is forced to use $2$nd quantization. Also it is possible to experimentally distinguish between the $2$.